# how to learn computer vision programming and real-time image processing basic concepts

Tags: python, algorithm, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I am searching in the `Computer Vision` topic, I don't have any previous experience.I found a good library `OpenCv` with `python` interfacing .I have started reading it's documentation, but I have faced many new concepts and names, that I am not familiar with, such as `Compute the Laplacian` , `GoodFeaturesToTrack`, `CreateMat` and many others

So my questions is what I have to study before starting with this library, to understand the functions of the library ?

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend a book by OpenCV author Gary Bradski - [*Learning OpenCV: Computer Vision with the OpenCV Library*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516134).

It is not only a refence how to use OpenCV, but also a comprehensive book on many computer vision topics, with many images that illustrate the concepts. It guides you through OpenCV basics, then trough image processing using filters, convolutions, histograms, contours, segmentation, tracking, camera calibration and 3D vision.

It is relatively easy to read (not too much math, just enough), I liked it really much.

Comment: It looks very useful book, after reading such book, what may I do with these skills I have earned from this book? (It may be strange question)

Comment: You will learn the basic building blocks to accomplish various tasks that take an image as input, like detection of blobs (for example for tracking), comparison of images, rotating them, equalizing histograms to enhance images, change colors, etc.

Comment: That is a good book but the current version is outdated. The authors are working on a 2nd edition that uses OpenCV's new C++ syntax and data structures. Until then, the book _OpenCV 2 Computer Vision Application Programming Cookbook_ is probably a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you the book of [gonzalez and woods - Digital image processing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013168728X) for the image processing basics.

there is a book on opencv but is for version 1.0. It is a decent [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516134) anyway.

Anyway openCV is a good library image processing but you would still need the basics of programming (don't forget this).

Comment: thank you, but unfortunately, I can't buy books from amazon !

Comment: there are some other sources than amazon (just pointed out amazon because they have all the book informations). It is so strange that I can send you a private message inside stack overflow.

Comment: I have send you an email (on your hotmail account). have a look on the spam folder if you don't get the email.